# If $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ there exists $(x_i)$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{f'(x_i)}=n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \to\mathbb R$ be differentiable, with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1 $. Prove that, for every $n\in \mathbb N$, there exists $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in[0,1]$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{f'(x_i)}=n$$

Comment: i use Mean value theorem to find f'.yes i prove for n=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, there exists $x$ such that $f(1)-f(0)=f'(x)(1-0)$. Take $x_i=x$ for every $i\geqslant1$.

Comment: You mean the mean value theorem, not the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Indeed I do. Thanks.

Comment: @did:thanks sir